# How do I disable CSRF in Django1.7?

Tags: django, django-views, django-csrf

It seems @csrf_exempt doesn't work anymore from Django 1.4, I have been trying to use different solutions which I have found on StackOverflow, such as removing a few middleware classes or adding a custom one, but I can't stop getting "CSRF Verification Failed". I just need to disable it for a login view that I am using with my Android app.

Comment: "It seems"? I don't know where you got that impression, but it is false, as you can see from [the 1.7 CSRF docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/csrf/#csrf-protection-should-be-disabled-for-just-a-few-views).

Comment: How do you enable the middleware though?

Comment: What? The middleware is obviously enabled, otherwise you wouldn't get verification failures.

Comment: I have set the csrf_exempt both on the url itself and before the view, but I am still getting "CSRF Verification Failed".

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Class Based Views, you could use [django-braces](https://django-braces.readthedocs.org/en/v1.4.0/form.html#csrfexemptmixin) which has a Mixin for that:

```
class UpdateProfileView(CsrfExemptMixin, LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Profile
```

Comment: I am not using Class Based Views, are there any other alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

according to [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/csrf/#django.views.decorators.csrf.csrf_exempt) the decorator @csrf_exempt should still work

maybe your login page is hitting multiple urls and you didn't exempt all of them?

Comment: I have imported the csrf_exempt and added the decorator before the view, but I am still getting "CSRF Verification Failed".

Comment: there is probably something wrong with your code. so impossible to say without looking at it. but this sounds like it is spanning across urls.py, views.py, and the html code...

Comment: What do you mean by hitting multiple ursl? I am just sending a username and password to /login.